# Databricks featurestore and unity catalog

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I created a databricks feature table, but saw that it by default went under hive_metastore. I was expecting to see it under the unity catalog that I have created. Is featurestore not integrated with unity catalog yet?

Answer (score 1):

Right now (November 2022nd), feature store doesn't support unity catalog.  This integration is expected early next year, but it's hard to say right now. You can reach your Databricks solution architect or customer success engineer to get more information about expected dates.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks has implemented many of the perks that were isolated to the Feature Store in Unity Catalog (UC). Any Delta table with a primary key can be a [Feature Table in UC](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/feature-store/uc/feature-tables-uc.html).

[Here are some helpful example notebooks](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/feature-store/example-notebooks.html)